# Display filtered value and grand total in the same sheet

Tags: tableau-api

I have a data source which is a database table where I group the number of active customers by SalesOwner.
[image]

What I want to do is filter my sheet using SalesOwner so that I can make a bar chart that contains one of SalesOwners *together with the Grand Total*. What happens as of now is that when I filter my data and select one SalesOwner, the Grand Total obviously shows the grand total of that one filter.

Is there a way around this? A bar chart with just one of SalesOwners and the total?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a fixed level of detail expression:
https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_lod_overview.html

In this case, something like `{FIXED : COUNTD(wk_customer)}`. You would create a calculated field named Grand Total that uses that calculation.

Comment: Sorry for the weekend delay. Let me try it our and come back to you.